# I want to downgrade my application target sdk version 29 to 28 can google play console allowed this?

Tags: android, google-play

I just submitted my application with target SDK version 29 but I am facing some crashes can I downgrade it to 28 and submit it again?

Comment: No! Google doesn't allow this. You only can publish a completely new app.

Comment: @Sam - that's true only specifically when moving from a `targetSdkVersion` of 26+ to something below API 26, it does not apply to this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can upload a new version that downgrades your `targetSdkVersion` - the [Google Play target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) only requires targeting API 28 or higher.

Note that it is expected that target API level requirement will increase each year, so you'll have to fix your app to work when targeting API 29 before ~late 2020.