# Can I downgrade target SDK version when update new version in Google PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play

Can I downgrade target SDK version from 30 to 29 when I upload new version in PlayStore?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362619/google-play-store-does-not-downgrade-the-target-sdk-version-in-my-updated-applic

Comment: when I read this post  @UsamaAltaf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674327/i-want-to-downgrade-my-application-target-sdk-version-29-to-28-can-google-play-c and I seen this answer is PlayStore is accepted .this make me confuse.So anyone have experienced help me??

Comment: In my link the last answer is also saying Adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="Your min Sdk version here" />` in AndroidManifest.xml works as of Nov 2020

Comment: but my question is target SDK not min SDK version

Comment: @Michael I not try it yet?So can you help me?

Comment: User that answered duplicate question is Android engineer working at Google. Since using API 30 is not yet required, and you are not downgrading below API 23. You are good to go.

Comment: Hi @DalijaPrasnikar I read some answer in here android someone said  PlayStore not accept like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362619/google-play-store-does-not-downgrade-the-target-sdk-version-in-my-updated-applic and some one said PlayStore accept like  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674327/i-want-to-downgrade-my-application-target-sdk-version-29-to-28-can-google-play-c .and this make me confuse .So i need to confirm this.Can you help me .thanks

Comment: Like I already said, yes you can downgrade from 30 to 29.